# Hi, I'm new to programming, how do I execute this code?

Tags: matrix

```py
def cubomagico (matriz,fil,col,c,n):
        if(c==n*n):
            matriz[n-1][col]=c
        else:
            if(fil<0 and col==n):
                cubomagico(matriz, fil+2,n-1, c, n)
            else:
                if(fil<0):
                    cubomagico(matriz,n-1,col,c,n)
                else:
                    if(col==n):
                        cubomagico(matriz,fil,0,c,n)
                    else:
                        if(matriz[fil][col]==0):
                            matriz[fil][col]=c
                            cubomagico(matriz, fil-1,col+1,c+1,n)
                        else:
                            cubomagico(matriz, fil+2,col-1,c,n)
```

Comment: This is an English language site. Please ask your question in that language, or ask at [es.so] instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've slightly modifed your program.

Now, to run this program, there are steps outlined [here](https://realpython.com/python-first-steps/#code-an-example-count-to-10) or [here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-run-a-python-program-under-windows) .

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

def cubomagico(matriz,fil,col,c,n):
    if (c==n*n):
        matriz[n-1][col]=c
    elif (fil<0 and col==n):
        cubomagico(matriz, fil+2,n-1, c, n)
    elif (fil<0):
        cubomagico(matriz,n-1,col,c,n)
    elif (col==n):
        cubomagico(matriz,fil,0,c,n)
    elif (matriz[fil][col]==0):
        matriz[fil][col]=c
        cubomagico(matriz, fil-1,col+1,c+1,n)
    else:
        cubomagico(matriz, fil+2,col-1,c,n)

C,N=4,4
M=[[0]*C for i in range(0,N)]

cubomagico(M,1,1,C,N)

print(M)
```